# Moored to fate of transitional life

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

A humble beginning of a vinegar jar
With bummed out plums in the shape of a bar
The line stretched on earth like a thin little scar
Attached to my twin from afar.

Our negative thoughts we exchange all the time
So skilfully it was considered sublime
We'd be happy to work for no more than a dime
Unless, of course, you're a mime

My voice grew stronger, and now I scream
My words swim through air like fish in a stream
No matter how far, no range too extreme
Or so at least it would seem

Another rebirth, and I'm smarter again
Attached to my addicts as if with a chain
My only weakness - the power I drain
That seemingly none can sustain

I'll grant you the knowledge, if that's what you want
Imprison your mind, till you're tired and gaunt
Replace every hobby, pastime, and jaunt
But me you'll continue to flaunt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you

> a telephone?

A humble beginning of a vinegar jar

> Early experiments/prototypes used a acid-water solution as part of the apparatus. One can use vinegar in this scenario.

With bummed out plums in the shape of a bar

> 

The line stretched on earth like a thin little scar
Attached to my twin from afar.

> Early telephones were just two transmitter/receivers connected with a wire.

Our negative thoughts we exchange all the time
So skilfully it was considered sublime

> Telephones worked by exchanging electrical signals, i.e. negative electrons.

We'd be happy to work for no more than a dime

> 10 cent payphones were the norm for quite some time.

Unless, of course, you're a mime

> Obviously, a silent mime can't use a telephone.

My voice grew stronger, and now I scream

> Phones got better.

My words swim through air like fish in a stream

> Wireless and cellular.

No matter how far, no range too extreme
Or so at least it would seem

> Phones seem to work "everywhere"; but one can easily find dead zones.

Another rebirth, and I'm smarter again

> Smartphones.

Attached to my addicts as if with a chain

> People these days are awfully attached to their phones.

My only weakness - the power I drain
That seemingly none can sustain

> With great power comes great battery drainability.

I'll grant you the knowledge, if that's what you want

> "Google/Wikipedia/IMDB/Reddit says here that..."

Imprison your mind, till you're tired and gaunt
Replace every hobby, pastime, and jaunt

> Games, TV, social interaction: all available on your phone.

But me you'll continue to flaunt

> Everyone loves to show off their new phone.

Comment: You, sir, are absolutely correct! Now, can you still guess the title and the second line? The second line ties into the first one heavily and describes the same thing.
The title has a name in it.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a poem talking about

> Electricity?

A humble beginning of a vinegar jar / 
With bummed out plums in the shape of a bar /
The line stretched on earth like a thin little scar /
Attached to my twin from afar.

> Pickles contain sodium ions, which can be used as a makeshift battery.  [A common scientific experiment in schools.](https://www.exploratorium.edu/cooking/pickles/activity-kosher_dill.html)

Our negative thoughts we exchange all the time /
So skilfully it was considered sublime /
We'd be happy to work for no more than a dime /
Unless, of course, you're a mime

> Electrons carry an electric charge, and dimes can conduct electricity.

My voice grew stronger, and now I scream /
My words swim through air like fish in a stream /
No matter how far, no range too extreme /
Or so at least it would seem

> Tesla's concept for [wireless tranmission of electricity](http://www.teslasociety.com/tesla_tower.htm).

Another rebirth, and I'm smarter again /
Attached to my addicts as if with a chain /
My only weakness - the power I drain /
That seemingly none can sustain

> Conventional, wired electronics, which are attached to a battery/outlet using a wire, and continuously drain power from the source.

I'll grant you the knowledge, if that's what you want /
Imprison your mind, till you're tired and gaunt /
Replace every hobby, pastime, and jaunt /
But me you'll continue to flaunt

> Electricity powers computers and the internet, which provide knowledge but can also be addicting, however a modern lifestyle can't be supported without electiricty.

Comment: You are close, but not quite.